# How do I get jenkins to build at a precise time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-build-flow

I am using jenkins along with the build flow plug-in. I would like my project built at precise times, but jenkins seems to only run on a schedule that is relative to the time the schedule is applied.

I want the project to build at precisely 4:00,8:00,12:00,16:00,20:00,00:00.

both "00 */4 * * *" and "01 0,4,8,12,16,20 * * *" fail to start the job at the precise times specified.

"00 */4 * * *" seems to really mean "00 */4 * * * + now"

I want my scheduled downtimes to be predictably scheduled, instead of starting at 8:38 because thats when I enabled the job.

Comment: I had a build set to `40 * * * *` and it started how I expected it in a 1minute time frame. Did you try `0 */4 * * *`? I will give it another try but have to wait 20 more minutes...

Comment: `0 * * * *` as well as `05 * * * *` triggered a test build. Didn't try "00".

Comment: is how you expected 40 minutes from now or every hour at the 40th minute?

Comment: yes. it run in the above examples at 41 past, 1 past and 6past.

Comment: I ran `00 */4 * * *` over the last 12 hours and it worked as expected. It ran 8:01 AM, 4:01 AM , 12:01 AM, 8:01 PM